# Issue with TubeFilter when setting normals to polydata in vtk.js

Tags: filter, vtk, normals, vtk.js

I can set my own normals to a polydata (lines) in vtk.js, and it works fine. But when I try to use a TubeFilter with said polydata, it doesn't work; I can only generate the tube if I don't set the normals. The program doesn't run any code after calling `tubeFilter.update()`.

I create my normals as so:

```
  const numSegments  = 1;
  const normals = new Float32Array(3 * (numSegments + 1));
  const normalArray = vtkDataArray.newInstance({
    name: 'Normals',
    values: normals,
    numberOfComponents: 3,
  });

  for(let i=0; i&lt;numSegments + 1; i++) {
    normals[i*3+0] = 0;
    normals[i*3+1] = 0;
    normals[i*3+2] = 1;
  }
```

And set it to the polydata as so:

`polyData.getPointData().setNormals(normalArray);`

I create the tube filter as so:

```
const tubeFilter = vtkTubeFilter.newInstance();
tubeFilter.setCapping(false);
tubeFilter.setNumberOfSides(50);
tubeFilter.setRadius(0.1);
tubeFilter.setInputData(polyData);
tubeFilter.setInputArrayToProcess(0, 'Scalars', 'PointData', 'Scalars');
tubeFilter.update(); // Program stops here
```

Why isn't it working? What am I doing wrong? What do I have to do to generate a tube with my own normals?
Here's the full code: [index.js](http://vtk.1045678.n5.nabble.com/file/t342808/index.js); it's a simplified version of [this example](https://kitware.github.io/vtk-js/examples/TubeFilter.html).

[Here's an image](http://vtk.1045678.n5.nabble.com/file/t342808/img.jpg) of the line with the tube generated when no normals are set (left) and only the line when normals are set (right), as the code stops after trying to generate the tube.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `SetDefaultNormal` function of `vtkTubeFilter` class. Just use it like this and ignore creating vector normals and then put them into the line:

```js
const tubeFilter = vtkTubeFilter.newInstance();
tubeFilter.setCapping(false);
tubeFilter.setNumberOfSides(50);
tubeFilter.setRadius(0.1);
tubeFilter.setInputData(polyData);
tubeFilter.useDefaultNormalOn();
tubeFilter.setDefaultNormal(0,0,1);
tubeFilter.setInputArrayToProcess(0, 'Scalars', 'PointData', 'Scalars');
tubeFilter.update(); // Program stops here
```

Comment: That's exactly what I don't want to do. vtkTubeFilter generates some tubes wrong (sometimes, tubes at certain parts look 'twisted''), so I want to use my own normals.

Comment: Based on the picture you provided, I think your problem is not normal vectors. Your problem is really sharp and unsmooth changes in your guiding curve specially in the area of crappy generated meshes. I think if you try to smooth your curve by using spline or something similar to spline interpolation, you will get a better result.